# Numerical integration of a derivative dataset

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, data-analysis

I have an experimentally measured derivative data ($\frac {dy}{dx}$) at a range of times i.e $\frac {dy}{dx}$ for $0 \le t \le tf$.

Integrating for $t=0$ is fine, since $y(x,0)$ is known. However, for each further timestep, I don't know how to compute the definite integral (just the indefinite relative integral result).

So, in summary, what is known is 
$\frac {dy}{dx}$ for all $t$ and $x$,
$y$ for $t=0$ and all $x$.

what I need to extract is y for all $t$ and $x$.

If I need to clarify, just let me know.

Comment: Since you have experimentally measured values for $dy/dx$, doesn't that mean you only know its value at some discrete collection of points, not *all* $t,x$?

Comment: Apologies, yes that is correct.

Comment: What is t here? f=f(x) or f=f(x,t)?

Comment: t is time,f = f(x,t). I have f'(x,t). I have f(x,0).

Comment: Perhaps I should provide context, to clarify. I have experimentally measured concentration gradients within a solution over a time period. I wish to determine the absolute concentrations from the data alone - I can determine the relative concentration at each time by simply integrating dC/dx by assigning an arbitrary concentration at x=0. 

I know the starting concentration of the solution, and thought there may be a method to calculate C(x,t) from this and the derivatives.

Comment: you measured dC(x(t),t)? Which means x is the difference between two concentrations which are varible both over a time period. Correct?

Comment: x is fixed with time i.e. it is a fixed sample space that does not change with time. At any sampling point in time, I have dC/dx for that time, hence I have dC(x,t).

Comment: You need to think about the equation governing the physical phenomenon, which is the diffusion equation.  That is the only way you can relate a time derivative (which you do not know) to your spatial derivative info.

Comment: I don't think you can do it unless you know either $dC/dt$ or $C(0,t)$.

Comment: @RonGordon, good idea, but there may also be convection, or the diffusion may be nonlinear, or any other number of complications that we can't deal with without more information from Tim.

Comment: @in_wolfram_we_trust: gotta start from somewhere.  In any case, the point is that the OP needs to consider the physics his data obeys.

Comment: I completely agree with Ron Gordon, and that is what I would prefer. I was trying to look for a way for just the data to talk, because it's a messy scenario of convection + diffusion + phase change. Although I do know $C(x,t_f)$ too, so I can crudely estimate $C(0,t)$ I suppose. I can also crudely approximate $C(0,t)$ with some form of a mass balance.

Comment: @Tim: let me know here how you make out.  I did similar things with such data many moons ago and liked what I saw.  I hope the same for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is governed by the diffusion equation:

$$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} = c \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

Here, you know $\partial y/\partial x$ for all $t$ and $x$ of interest, as well as $y(x,0)$ for all $x$ of interest.  I will assume you know $c$, or at least have an estimate.

You can approximate $\partial y/\partial t$ from your derivative data, but taking the numerical derivative of that data in $x$, and dividing by $c$.  From this, you may extract an approximation for $y$ at the next time step $t$.  This is admittedly crude, but it is a first step.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you know $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in some discrete points $t_i$. And you know $y_0$ and $x_0$ at $t_0$. So why do not you approximate the derivative like this $$\frac{y_{i+1}-y_{i}}{x_{i+1}-x_{i}} = \frac{dy}{dx}_{(i+1)}$$ and simply solve this equation. But to do this some additional information on $x$ or $y$ are required. Otherwise it seems the lack of information to find a solution.